# How to find whether Recordset is empty is not in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I tried the following code:

```
rs5.Open "select Duration from onduty where User_id='" & rs1!User_id & "' and date=#" & Date & "#", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

where `rs5`, `rs1` are declared as `ADODB.Recordset`.

I need to find where `rs5` after executing the query is empty or not.

Comment: Why didn't you read documentation? "If the data source returns no records, the provider sets both the BOF and EOF properties to True, and the current record position is undefined. You can still add new data to this empty Recordset object if the cursor type allows it." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am new to VB and I need to modify an earlier done project and I am appointment to that project. As the project is to be completed soon i have no time to read the documentation.

Comment: What kind of programmer are you, if you disregard documentation? What warranties can you supply to your code?

Comment: I usually read documentation and proceed further. Without documentation I wont do or proceed further. I was given a job to modify a project which was urgent and which was previously completed by some other. Almost I completed my job. Just for report generation the condition to generate the report was not working. I tried your suggestion earlier using EOF. But the mistake was at the other location in the program and debugged and finished the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try :

```
If rs5.EOF Then MsgBox "null"
```

Comment: Yes I tried it earlier. But the mistake was in the other part of  the program which I was working. Now I corrected it.Now My program is working correctly. Any way your answer is the answer to my question. So I accept it. Thank you for answering, as if you wont answer I would think that I have used a wrong condition. Now its clear for me.